# IE7 acronym underline in a fieldset legend

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, legend, fieldset, acronym

I have an acronym inside of a fieldset/legend:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>
        <acronym>foo</acronym>
    </legend>
</fieldset>
```

In Firefox this gets rendered with a dotted underline to signal the user that there is something there if they mouseover it.

In IE the dotted underline doesn't show up?

I tried forcing it in css like this:

```
style="border-bottom:1px dotted #000000 !important;"
```

But I can't seem to get it to show up.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the acronym's display style to `inline-block` That will let IE7 show the border you specify in the style.